# No muestra todos los datos de la base de datos mysql en mi tabla

Tags: php, html, mysql

Cuando ejecuto el código se come el primer registro que tengo en la base de datos. Ya revisé todo y no veo problema.

Como comento me aparecen todos menos el primer dato, lo cambié de orden al llamar los datos para ver si funcionaba pero desaparece el primer dato.

Este es el código donde visualizo los datos

```
<?php 
   include("bd.php");
   $con=conectar();
   session_start();

   $sql="SELECT * FROM crud";
   $query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

   $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);

 ?>
```

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
    <title>Inventario</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 </head>

 <body>
                <div class="d-grid gap-3">
                    <center>

                    <div  class="p-2 bg-light border">
                     <br>
                     <a href="ingresar.php" class="btn btn-success">NUEVO</a>
                     <br><br>
                        <table class="table table-bordered">
                         <caption>Piezas de arte</caption>
                            <thead class="thead-dark">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Codigo</th>
                              <th>Ciudad</th>
                              <th>Localizacion</th>
                              <th>Lugar_Exhibicion</th>
                              <th>Titulo</th>
                              <th>Fotografia</th>
                              <th>Tipo_bien</th>
                              <th>Medidas</th>
                              <th>Estado_obra</th>
                                    <th>Mas</th>
                                    
                                    
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <?php 
                                while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                                    
                                 ?>
                                 <tr>

                                 <th><?php echo $row['codigo']?></th>
                                 <th><?php echo $row['ciudad']?></th>
                                 <th><?php echo $row['localizacion']?></th>
                                 <th><?php echo $row['lugar_ex']?></th>
                                 <th><?php echo $row['nombre']?></th>
                                 <th><?php echo $row['fotografia']?></th>
                                 <th><?php echo $row['tipo_bien']?></th>
                                 <th><?php echo $row['medidas']?></th>
                                 <th><?php echo $row['estado']?></th>
                                      <th><a href="actualizar.php?id=<?php echo $row['codigo']?>" class="btn btn-info" title="Ver mas"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-chevron-down"> </i></a></th>
                                     
                                 </tr>
                                <?php 
                                   }
                                 ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
   
                    </div>
                
                </div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Y esta es la otra parte que básicamente es donde inserto los datos en la tabla...

```
<?php 

include("bd.php");
$con=conectar();

$codigo=$_POST['codigo'];
$ciudad=$_POST['ciudad'];
$localizacion=$_POST['localizacion'];
$lugar_ex=$_POST['lugar_ex'];
$nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
$nacionalidad=$_POST['nacionalidad'];
$fotografia=$_POST['fotografia'];
$epoca=$_POST['epoca'];
$fechado=$_POST['fechado'];
$autor=$_POST['autor'];
$tipo_bien=$_POST['tipo_bien'];
$caracter_bien=$_POST['caracter_bien'];
$material=$_POST['material'];
$tecnica=$_POST['tecnica'];
$medidas=$_POST['medidas'];
$descrip=$_POST['descrip'];
$estado=$_POST['estado'];
$estado_inte=$_POST['estado_inte'];

$sql="INSERT INTO crud VALUES('$codigo','$ciudad','$localizacion','$lugar_ex','$nombre','$nacionalidad','$fotografia','$epoca','$fechado','$autor','$tipo_bien','$caracter_bien','$material','$tecnica','$medidas','$descrip','$estado','$estado_inte')";

$query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if ($query) {
    header("Location: inventario.php");
} else {
    
}


 ?>
```

Comment: Hola, tu problema ocurre cuando quieres actualizar? o cuando vas a insertar?
Porque el código que nos muestras para visualizar los datos no es el formulario donde capturas por primera vez, sino donde actualizas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema está en el primer bloque de código, en la última línea:

```
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
```

Si observas en tu segundo bloque de código, hay una parte similar:

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    // ...
```

Recuerda, [mysqli_query](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) devuelve un objeto MySQL con todos los resultados. Ese objeto es recorrido por la instrucción `mysqli_fetch_*` (en tu caso [mysqli_fetch_array](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)), que mueve una especie de puntero al siguiente registro cada vez que es ejecutado.

Como ya hiciste una ejecución en el primer bloque, el puntero ahora se ha movido al segundo registro y por eso es que desde el HTML empieza desde el 2do.

En otras palabras, solo borra el `$row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);` del primer bloque de código.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! en verdad funciono, infinitas gracias.